# How to order nested eventlisteners in js

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have the following code in my js:

```js
const someElement = document.getElementById('some-element')
    
someElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log('The start of main event')
    
        const someOtherElement = document.getElementById('some-other-element')
        someOtherElement.addEventListener('load', function () {
            console.log("someOtherElement is invoked")
})
    
        console.log("This is the end of main event")
})
```

How to make this code run exactly in the order of the actual written code.
I want the following result:

The start of main event

someOtherElement is invoked

This is the end of main event

---

However when the code is run I get the following result:

The start of main event

This is the end of main event

someOtherElement is invoked

Comment: Unless you use promises or callbacks, it is not going to happen.

Comment: can you show how?

Comment: Also if they click more than once, you are going to be binding multiple events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's running this way because these are two different events run in two different functions. To fix this, you can use async JavaScript

```
const someElement = document.getElementById('some-element')

someElement.addEventListener('click', async function(){
  var p = new Promise(function(resolve, fail) {
    console.log('The start of main event')

    const someOtherElement = document.getElementById('some-other-element')
    someOtherElement.addEventListener('load', function () {
      console.log("someOtherElement is invoked")
      resolve(true);
    })
  });
  await p;
  console.log("This is the end of main event")
 })
```

Comment: what happens if `someOtherElement` is loaded before `someElement` gets clicked?

Comment: @GrafiCode A good question but extraneous to the question asked

Answer (score 1):

The load event will be called only once (after your element has loaded). For example, if you have an image for which you have put a load event, the load event will fire **only once** after the element has loaded. So, if you click `some-element` **after** `some-other-element` **has already loaded**, the load event will not fire.

Also, if `some-other-element` loads after `some-element` is clicked, it will log `someOtherElement invoked` after `The start of main event` and `This is the end of main event`.

**Remember:**
You can only add load events on `<body>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input type="image">`, `<link>`, `<script>`, and `<style>` tags.

**Edit:** As  @epascarello said in the comments, if you click `some-element` multiple times, it will add **multiple eventlisteners** to `some-other-element`. To fix this, you can have a variable:

```
const someElement = document.getElementById("some-element");
let eventBinded = false;

someElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("The start of main event");

    const someOtherElement = document.getElementById("some-other-element");

    if (!eventBinded) {
        eventBinded = true;

        someOtherElement.addEventListener("load", function () {
            console.log("someOtherElement is invoked");
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Event already binded");
    }

    console.log("This is the end of main event");
});
```